# Вконтакте - обрезаются картинки прикреплённые к посту

Tags: изображения, вконтакте

Есть картинка - логотип сайта, размеры 200х100px. Во Вконтакте, при добавлении к посту ссылки на сайт, ВК прикрепляет эту картинку, но обрезает.

Как сделать чтобы не обрезалась?

Посмотрел html ВК, там вроде прописаны габариты: *min-height: 63px;  width: 130px;*. Сделал таких размеров - не помогло.

В интернете нашёл только совет сделать размер 200х200, но тогда пострадает дизайн сайта.

- Скриншоты
- [При добавлении и редактировании поста ВК нормально опознаёт размер](https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/115238830027261390917/albums/5905225613345063313/5972884999164839826?pid=5972884999164839826&oid=115238830027261390917).
- [После записи показывает обрезок](https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/115238830027261390917/albums/5905225613345063313/5972884976960470114?pid=5972884976960470114&oid=115238830027261390917).

PS2: Уточнение html ВК. Для постов ПОСЛЕ записи там прописаны свойства: *height: 100%;  min-height: 63px; width: 100px;*. 
Уменьшил картинку до 100px - та же фигня.

PS3: Оказывается ВК кэширует картинки. Я сейчас экспериментировал с размерами, постил - никаких изменений. Проверил - а он первую так и показывает.

Answer (score 1):

Вроде как ВК умеет брать картинки из меты

```
<meta property="og:image" content="Адрес картинки">
```

Comment: Не помогло. ВКонтакт вроде нормально и так опознаёт картинки, обрезает их после записи поста. 

Добавил ссылки на скриншоты в вопрос.

Comment: @bl79 есть у меня такая мысль, что обрезание неизбежно.

Comment: Посмотрел как у других - у кого работает, у кого тоже нет.

Comment: Блин, оказывается ВК кэширует картинки. Я сейчас экспериментировал с размерами, постил - никаких изменений. Проверил - а он первую так и показывает.

Answer (score 0):

Сбросить кеш внешней страницы можно через метод API ВК **pages.clearCache** — http://vk.com/dev/pages.clearCache